# firebase: can't find variable IDBIndex

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm developing an app with react-native (v0.60) and I need push notifications. I decided to use firebase as service but I have an error during initialisation.

Code:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Config from 'react-native-config'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import '@firebase/messaging'

import firebaseConfig from 'App/src/firebase.config'
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = firebase.messaging()
messaging.usePublicVapidKey(Config.FIREBASE_KEY_PAIR)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

The problem is that I get the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: IDBIndex

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you by any chance start up firebase analytics somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

firebase only supports Authentication, Firestore & Realtime databases, Storage, and Functions on React Native. Other modules like Analytics are not supported through the Firebase JS SDK, but you can use expo-firebase-analytics for that. If you'd like access to the full suite of native firebase tools

please remove firebase.analytics();

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have enabled Google Analytics for your app. Disable Analytics from the Firebase settings and again copy the Firebase file data from Firebase and replace it with the old `firebase.js` file in the project.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the analytics and it fixed my error

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use the [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) wrapper instead. As [they say](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started#Why):

> Although some features from the Firebase Web SDK will generally work with React Native, it is mainly built for the web and as such has a limited compatible feature set. In contrast we use the Firebase Native SDKs - this allows us to provide APIs to a vast majority of Firebase products and services.

Answer (score 0):

please remove firebase.analytics();  form where ?